# Simple function using a lot of memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm using local storage because after the click, the page reloads, so I can keep track of the last item clicked.
As you can see, I've tried to clear localStorage in order to shrink the memory in use, but it's already at 1.000.000K in less then 10 minutes of usage.

Is this script redeclaring this variables at different location everytime my page reloads?
What is happening that is making it use so mant memory?
This is my entire code.
It's an extension I'm creating for chrome, it selects an option and clicks the button, the button submits a form, the page reload, and it does eveything again and again.

```
var last = localStorage.getItem('last');
var current = getNext(last);
var prox = getNext(current);

localStorage.clear();

$('select[name="myselect"] option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().indexOf(current)>-1){
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
        $('.abc').first().click();
        localStorage.setItem('last',current);
    }
});

function getNext(current){
    var arrIds = ['227','228','229','230','231','232'];
    return arrIds[arrIds.indexOf(current)+1] || '227';
}
```

**Updated code**, without var declarations, that has decreased memory consumption drastically, but with time, the memory raises (in ten minutes went from 160.000K to 240.000K):

```
$('select[name="myselect"] option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().indexOf(getNext(localStorage.getItem('last')))>-1){
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
        $('.abc').first().click();
        localStorage.setItem('last',getNext(localStorage.getItem('last')));
    }
});

function getNext(current){
    var arrIds = ['227','228','229','230','231','232'];
    return arrIds[arrIds.indexOf(current)+1] || '227';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me as if this code could be responsible for your observed memory consumption.

Comment: When you say "the page reloads", is it actually reloading, or are you just updating its content somehow? If you remove the code above, does it fix the leak?

Comment: Pointy, this is all my code. Squint, the page actually reloads entirely when the click is performed, I'll try to not use the vars.

Comment: If the page is truly reloading (clicking a link or something), it shouldn't leak. Which browser(s) show this behavior? EDIT: ...I now see it's a chrome extension.

Comment: It's an extension I'm creating for chrome, it selects an option and clicks the button, the page reload, it does eveything again and again.

Comment: What does the button do? Is it submitting a form?

Comment: Strange. So eliminating just the `localStorage` parts of the code eliminates the leak, right?

Comment: squint, I've removed all the variables declaration, and called the values directly from the localstorage, now it's using 140.000K to 160.000K, and raising the memory usage really slowly, but is raising. I'll make the test without `localStorage`, but I think that is declaring variables to new adresses every time the page reloads.

Comment: How are you measuring the consumption?

Comment: Xan, chrome task manager, memory indicator.

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: squint, latest, 37.0.2062.124(64-bit).

Comment: If you have Dev Tools open, their logs, especially network logs, can account for memory "leak".

Comment: I'm not a Chrome extension developer, but reviewing some of the introductory material, I see there's a concept of a "background page", which are labeled as "persistent" or "event". The "persistent" label makes it sound like it could have something to do with what's going on, but that's just a guess. Does your extension use such a background page?

Comment: I'm not using background page, I'm only using two JS files, that I've set it on the property `content_scripts` on `manifest.json`. One is `jquery.min.js` the other is `my.js`, that contains the script on the question. Removing the variables, and accessing it directly from the localStorage, decreased memory usage drastically, but it still continues to raise with time, like in ten minutes, it raised from 160.000K to 240.000K. I'm going to update my code in the question.

Comment: According to the profiler, what exactly is accumulating memory? Does `jQuery.cache` grow in size?

Comment: I've took a look at the profiles, couldn't find jQuery.cache, I'll try to find it, but this is the difference of profiles in about 15 seconds, the profile got like 2.7MB bigger in this time. Note that it's ordered by Shallow Size http://i.imgur.com/U8sLMn4.png

Comment: May be worth just going ahead and filing a bug report.

Comment: squint, thank you very much for your help! I didn't know about profiles, I'll try to understand it better. I guess you are right, jQuery might be leaving garbage behind.

Comment: Try eliminating jQuery code. It is known to leak badly in some cases. Rewrite it without jQuery and see if the leak persists. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: @squint, I'll try to do that with pure javascript, again, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @squint, just wanted to say that I've made it with pure JS and it's running with 60.000K MAX of memory usage! It's really, really fast!!! I'm really happy!! Fell free to answer this question, by saying to use pure JS, it really worked handsomely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments below the question, the issue appears to come from jQuery itself. The exact reason isn't known at this point, but it appears jQuery has retained data that is not being released when the form is submitted.

This probably has to do in part with some aspect of it being a Chrome extension, since typically on a refresh, the browser would release all memory including globals.

jQuery creates great potential for memory leaks by holding data and closures in a global reference called `jQuery.cache`. If this is not cleaned up properly, leaks abound.

Since you're creating a Chrome extension, there shouldn't be much to compel you to use jQuery, since you'll not need to worry about browser incompatibility from browsers like IE6 and 7. By using the DOM API directly without such dependencies, the overall code will be smaller and *much* faster.